# Как создать прямую ссылку на конференцию Zoom?

Tags: url, uri, zoom

Задача стоит в том, чтобы ссылка вела прямо в Zoom. Я не знаю, как называется этот формат ссылок, вроде бы *абсолютная*. Например, в телеге формат такой tg://resolve?domain=d_code. При нажатии сразу открывается необходимый канал или чат. Эту ссылку я просто скопировал нажатием на зелёную кнопку. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но скопировать прямую ссылку на Zoom не получается. Вроде, запускается код на JavaScript, который уже генерирует необходимую ссылку и просто не даёт её скопировать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл пример [здесь](https://medium.com/zoom-developer-blog/zoom-url-schemes-748b95fd9205)

zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=1234567890&pwd=PASSWORD